# Extracting specific info from a string in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, char

Python3.7

The following is my input:

a "Random road" (1,2) (2,3) (3,4)

a is my command to add a road. Next comes the name of the road followed by its location. I need to extract the name of the road.

I wish to extract the name of the road and its coordinates and store in in separate lists.
I am able to extract the integers using re but i am unable to extract the name of the road. 
How do I extract only the road name and store it in a separate string.

Comment: I'm not sure is everything a string
`a= "'Random Road' (1,2) (2,3)(3,4)"`

Comment: Hi! Please share the entire code and what you have attempted so we can better understand what it is that you want to get done. Share an example if possible.

Comment: a "'Random Road' (1,2) (2,3)(3,4)"

Comment: @AkashPawar Do NOT put it in the comments.  The question is yours so edit the question and add that information to the question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using a split method ?

```
test_str = "Random Road (1,2) (2,3)(3,4)" 
print(test_str.split("(")[0].strip())

'Random Road'
```

**Edit** : added simpler method if road name is between quotes

```
import re
test_str = """a "Random Road" (1,2) (2,3)(3,4)"""
print(re.findall('"([^"]*)"', test_str))
['Random Road']
```

Comment: test_str = a "Random Road"  (1,2) (2,3) (3,4)     The output must be just Random road,without the quotes. Input is with quotes

Comment: what is the [a] for ? test_str is equal to this """a "Random Road" (1,2) (2,3) (3,4)""" ?

Comment: a is my command which indicates that the following road needs to be added. Likewise r would denote removal of an existing road. test_str = a "Road name" (1,2) (2,2) (3,3) .

Comment: the var test_str = a "Road name" (1,2) (2,2) (3,3) will generate an error if you run it as is. Please give the exact value you assign to the variable test_str

Comment: your edit solution worked. thanks a lot. can you please explain it

Comment: s=str(input()) this is the exact syntax for input

Comment: @AkashPawar: There is no reason to do `str(input())` on Python 3. `input()` is already guaranteed to return a `str` (or raise an exception), so the `str()` wrapping is a pointless, slightly wasteful no-op. `s = input()` would accomplish the same thing, with less waste.

Comment: @snat2100 Thanks a lot bro.